# fancybox v3 beta not running on ajax loaded content

Tags: jquery, ajax, fancybox

Niche question, hoping some other people have been using fancybox too.

On my site, I have subpages that are loaded using the .load() jquery function.  Thus, I need to put almost all my scripts in the primary index.html file.

Using this method, I had the fancybox v2 running fine - with the script:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.fancybox').fancybox();
});
```

on the main index page, rather than on the photo page.

I tried to update to fancybox v3 to use the touch controls for mobile, but now this same method isn't working.

Has anyone dealt with this problem, or have a solution?  Applying scripts to .load(ed) content can be tricky, but I thought I had this figured out.

Recommendations for other good mobile/touch enabled lightboxes are also cool.